# Bitmap Matrix postRotate changes X and Y axis direction

Tags: android, canvas, matrix

I'm trying to rotate my Bitmap using a readymade solution I found somewhere. The code is below:

```
      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                float x = ship.Position.left;
                float y = ship.Position.top;
                canvas.drawBitmap(ship.ship, x,y,null);
                invalidate();
      }
```

However, when I do it, the X and Y axii change their direction - if I increase the Y the image goes towards the top of the screen, not towards the bottom. Same happens to X if I rotate by 90 degrees.

I need to rotate it but without changing the Y and X axii directions.

Even rotated, I still want the Bitmap to go towards the bottom if I increase Y and to the right if I increase the X.

```
     public void update()
     {
       if(!moving)
         {
           fall();
         }
       else //moving
         {
           move();
          faceDirection();
         }
       Position.top += Speed;
      }

private void move() {
   if(Speed < MAXSPEED)
        Speed -= 0.5f;  
 }
private void fall() {
    if(Speed > MAXSPEED*-1)
    Speed += 0.2f;  
 }
private void faceDirection() {

    double OldDiretion = Direction;
    Direction = DirectionHelper.FaceObject(Position, ClickedDiretion);
    if (Direction != OldDiretion)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate((float)Direction);
        ship = Bitmap.createBitmap(ship, 0, 0, ship.getWidth(),ship.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }
```

I tried the code above, but it's still changing the Y direction, It's going to bottom of the BitMap, not bottom of the screen.

Here is the project: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8V9oTk0eiOKOUZJMWtsSmUtV3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to clarify, you DON'T want it to rotate around the center point, but around the top-left corner?

Comment: I want it to rotate where the user touches, but the gravity will still push the bitMap to bottom, now, it's like this: if you click top, the "gravity" changes, and the bitmap is going to TOP not to bottom because it's rotated (180) and I don't want it.

Comment: Could you post the part of your code, where you change the x/y and observe the anomalous behavior?

Comment: Updated the question, there it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should first rotate, than translate:

```
matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
matrix.postRotate(degree);
```

alternative would be to try to use `preRotate()` instead of `postRotate()`.

I also strongly recommend to translate/rotate the original while drawing. So your `createBitmap()` call shouldn't modify the orientation. At least not when you change it dynamically on user interaction. Otherwise you would create a lot of bitmaps to represent rotations over and over again which would impact the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't actually rotate the bitmap - you just draw it rotated. So, the next time you redraw it, you first push it towards the bottom or right by incrementing x/y and then rotate it.

You have to actually rotate the bitmap itself. You could use the following code:

```
ship.ship = Bitmap.createBitmap(ship.ship, 0, 0, ship.ship.getWidth(), ship.ship.getHeight(), matrix, false);
```

Here you create a new rotated bitmap and set your reference to point to it.

**Note!** You must do this only once! So you can't do it in the `onDraw` method, since then it will get rotated every time it's redrawn. You have to do it somewhere else and then draw it as usual in `onDraw` (without the matrix rotations).

Comment: It's still not working, I changed the code of the question, check again PLEASEEE!

Comment: In the end of the question, there's the project.